# Naming Conventions for C# class generation with protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I managed to get as far as generating C# classes from `.proto` files on build but the properties of my objects are in camel case instead of pascal case which is preferred.

[This page](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/contract_first.html) mentions the usage of additional options to modify the behaviour of the build tool but nowhere can I find how to actually specify the values of these options.

Additionally, how would I go about defining the namespace for generated classes within the `.csproj` file?